Where should database calls that return primitive types be located and who should be calling them, Application Services or Domain Services?
As far as I know Repositories should work with Domain/Business Entities. All the operations to save and retrieve data to create entities should go there, and then the Repository is used by the Domain Services etc. The repository Definition should be in the Domain Layer and the Implementation should be in the Infrastructure layer, I understand that. What I'm having hard time understanding is where should code like getting some list of values from table that is used to fill a drop-down list for example, or some query to get needed data to call Domain Service based on the input that the user has provided, be implemented and who is the user of these classes/methods? Another example is a query that should check some condition(business rule maybe?) in database in order to continue execution.
Should they reside in some DAL(Data Access Layer) as DAO(Data Access Objects) of some sort where you have methods that return primitive types(or enumerations of them) that is separate form the Repository? Should they be called directly by the Application Layer and the Domain Layer or should they be mediated through some sort of mechanism? Should the Repository be implemented using these classes/methods also or should it be independent? For simplicity let's say we are using ORM like Entity Framework or Hibernate.

As a general rule, your domain model's responsibility is to act upon information that is available in local (transient) memory.  The work of making that information available in local memory belongs... somewhere else.  Not in the "domain model".
The domain model code should not usually be tightly coupled to the fact that your reference data is stored in a singleton / in a file on disk / in a database / behind an HTTP facade on the network / etc.
The point being that we should be able to change these details without the risk of introducing subtle errors in the domain logic.  In effect, we're performing information hiding -- isolating the domain model from unrelated changes.
This isn't too different from one of the motivations of the repository pattern; that we be able to work in the domain logic without being distracted by all of the technical concerns associated with reconstituting the entities in local memory.

Beyond that, the rules are basically the same as you would use anywhere else - you want to move program elements closer to other elements with the similar dependencies that change on a similar schedule, and keep them further away from elements that change for different reasons.

Just to confirm, data access that is not concerned with loading domain entities into memory should go in separate component as per CCP (Common Closure Principle) and CRP(Common Reuse Principle), that is different from where the Repository (working with domain entities) is implemented? Of course the policy/interface for the Repository is defined in the Domain Layer. What about usage of this non-entity access "Repository"?  For an example, there is a rule which states 'Controllers should be as thin as possible'. So should controllers call directly this DAO, or should it be mediated somehow?
